# Concatenate array with define and varaible - c language

Tags: c

I am looking for a solution to concatenate in a array with value from defines and variable. I have already try with memcpy like that but it not working :

```
#define ADDRESS   {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x45}
#define SIGNATURE {0xC6, 0x54, 0x2D}
uint8_t packetCounter = 0;
uint8_t RadioData[2]={'2','1'};

uint8_t Packet = sizeof(uint8_t);

memcpy(Packet, ADDRESS, sizeof(ADDRESS));
memcpy(Packet, SIGNATURE, sizeof(SIGNATURE));
memcpy(Packet, packetCounter, sizeof(packetCounter));
memcpy(Packet, data, sizeof(data));
```

The goal of this code is to have an array with those value : ADDRESS+SIGNATURE+packetCounter+data. And I would like also to add "_" between each variable after.

Do you have any solution? 
Thanks

Comment: `memcpy(Packet, (uint8_t[])ADDRESS, sizeof( (uint8_t[])ADDRESS));`. Check out [compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5). But your `Packet` definition is bad.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, sadly.

Comment: I would do it with a packed struct type but, no matter how you do it, you must allocate enough memory somewhere.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The arrays being used are rvalues, so that doesn't work.

Comment: C language - why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: @Cppplus1 What rvalues? These are macros. But surely one should keep track where the previous copy did end to not overwrite that chunk.

Comment: Are you allowed to change `ADDRESS` and `SIGNATURE` into constant arrays, instead of macros?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use the macros to define constant arrays. As it is, they are just text in the source, so they don't have memory to copy.

Comment: I'm not sure what the last comment about adding "_" was trying to say.

Comment: Please choose a single language, C or C++.  For example, C++ has `std::copy` and C doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what it is you want, but maybe something like this?

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define ADDRESS 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x45
#define SIGNATURE 0xC6, 0x54, 0x2D

void Some_Function(void) {
    uint8_t packetCounter = 0;
    uint8_t RadioData[2]={'2','1'};

    uint8_t Packet[] = {ADDRESS, SIGNATURE, packetCounter, RadioData[0], RadioData[1]};
}
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it if everything is a literal, in which case RadioData should be done the same way as the others. However, I get the impression RadioData and other things are added to a variable sized packet.

Comment: Possibly.  It wasn't super clear what exactly the OP really needed.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy way worked fine for me. I see the exact bytes in the packet, in my debugger.

```
#include <vector>

#define ADDRESS   {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x45}
#define SIGNATURE {0xC6, 0x54, 0x2D}

uint8_t address[] ADDRESS;
uint8_t signature[] SIGNATURE;
uint8_t packetCounter = 0;
uint8_t RadioData[2] = { '2','1' };

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> packet;

    std::copy(std::begin(address), std::end(address), std::back_inserter(packet));
    std::copy(std::begin(signature), std::end(signature), std::back_inserter(packet));
    packet.push_back(packetCounter);
    std::copy(std::begin(RadioData), std::end(RadioData), std::back_inserter(packet));

    // packet now has the bytes expected
    return 0;
}
```

This is c++, although the question had both tags. I can put them in a malloc'ed area just as easily if you need C. Also the #define is completely unnecessary. I'd rather just define static const arrays.

I probably would have used unsigned char or char, possibly with a static assert if they need to be 8 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `Packet` is an integer variable.  The `memcpy` needs a pointer, not an integer variable.  Your trying to copy a lot of bytes to a single byte location.